# How much difference in electric permittivity between two systems must there be to form a standing wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dielectric, resonance

Dielectric resonator's operational basis rests on the basis that, upon exposure to electromagnetic radiation, should the difference in electric permittivity, or their dielectric constant be sufficiently high, a standing wave will form. The question is, how much of a difference must this be?

Answer (score 0):

If the resonator is large enough then $\epsilon_r$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$. Think of what confines the field: total internal reflection and if the angle between the ray and surface is mall enough you can have arbitrarily small difference, at least in principle, to get total reflection. Now whether that is practical is another issue.

In Collin: FOUNDATIONS FOR MICROWAVE ENGINEERING, 2nd ed, pp 510-513 you can find the exact resonance equation Eq.7.69 for a spherical dielectric resonator of radius $a$ and permittivity $\epsilon_r$:
$$ (\eta^2 +\mathfrak {j}\eta x -1)\mathrm{sin} x - [(\eta ^2 -1)x+\mathfrak {j} \eta x^2 -\frac{1}{3}x^3] \mathrm{cos} x =0$$ where $\eta = \sqrt{\epsilon_r}$ is the refractive index and $x=\eta k_0 a$ is the "reduced" resonance frequency.

This is a nasty complex equation whose root $x$ gets you the resonant wave number $k_0$. There is no obvious reason why this could not be solved for any $\eta >1$ if $a$ is large enough but I do not have a proof. Collin suggests an iterative solution for large $\eta$ starting with the first root $x_0\approx 4.9$ of $x \mathrm{sin}x -\mathrm{cos}x=0$ and then linearize the Taylor series around $x_0$ but this would fail for small $\eta$. The root must be complex because there is always some radiative losses unless you confine the dielectric in a metal box.